# Restart the go application when the error

Tags: go, restart, application-restart

I have an go application running 24 hours a day. Does anyone have an idea for a separate application that looks up whether the main application is running? If the main application has a bug, an additional application should close the main application and re-run the main application. Or maybe there is something in the style of the destructor, which could be the main application?

Comment: On what platform is your main application running? On Linux you could use [watchdog](http://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog) to look for a specific PID.

Comment: Use one of many daemon runners: [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), [daemon tools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html), [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), [runsit](https://github.com/bradfitz/runsit), ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of returned `error`s it's the task of your application to handle them correctly and restart the appropriate parts. It get's harder in case of `panic`s. Here Go provides `recover`. It's like a `catch` of exceptions.

In https://github.com/tideland/goas I provide `loop`, a package to run goroutines in a controlled way. Beside a traditional approach with the ability to stop a goroutine and/or retrieve an error value in case it died you can also start a goroutine with `GoRecoverable`. It provides a way to pass a function that's called in case of a panic and also knows about count and frequency. So it can act or decide if a goroutine shall continue work (e.g. by resetting/re-initializing those parts of your code that are covered by the failure).